# Debugging not working in a service class ?? what can cause this issue?

Tags: android, android-manifest

All of a sudden I am not able to debug anything that i am doing in a service even though i put breakpoints all over. but logging shows that all the lines are getting executed. Can someone tell me what could be causing this issue. I am using eclipse and i have set to "Build automatically".

Comment: how are you starting the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have an `Activity` which is launched at the beginning of your application?

If not you have to manually activate the debug on your process by using the **DDMS tool** in Eclipse.

In `DDMS -> Devices`, check your process (the line contains the package name of your app), select it and then click on the debug button. A debug icon will appear near your process, then you should be able to use breakpoints in your `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Runnable try placing this in the run() method:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```