# Can I debug a service when the application quits or closed in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM Cloud messaging to get notifications. While Google search I found that When application either in background state or quit, data payload received on "onMessageReceived" method of FirebaseMessagingService service.

What my question is, How can I debug the services when the application is closed or quit(not running) state.

If I can't please suggest me any better alternative to check the flow in the services.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004711/how-to-debug-an-android-background-service)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Logcat to log the events happening in the `Service` to understand.

Example:

`Log.d(TAG, "onStart()");`

2. In case you you want to specifically debug then follow the articles mentioned by @brat.

[Debugging a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008081/debugging-a-service)

Note: Make sure your `Service` is running in the background.