# My SyncAdapter doesnt execute at all

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I am implementing a sync functinality for my app , it is executing the sync code after specified amount of time i.e. after 15 mins (for now), but the code in my custom SyncAdapter doesn't get executed.

I have defined my service in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
 <service
            android:name="packagename.SyncService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":sync" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
```

and I have implemented `onPerformSync()` in custom SyncAdapter , but this code never gets executed,

also `onCreate() or onStartCommand()` of SyncService is never invoked,
any pointers with respect to this might be helpful,

P.S :Have read many similar questions on this forum,but none have helped my cause,

Comment: How are you debugging this? using logs or setting break points?

Comment: Check your `service path`. is it right? your service never got called

Comment: @DegenSharew setting up break-points

Comment: @MD yes service path (i.e. android:name) exactly matches the fully qualified path for my service

Comment: So that wont work as the code is executed by a d/t process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Debugging sync adapter**

Use **logging** instead of putting debugging breakpoints as your code executed by a different process.

Normally breakpoints will work only for main process running your app which is not the case for your sync adapter code; it is run by a different process.

---

Also check [debugging service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008081/debugging-a-service).